# Is .NET 6 backwards compatible with applications developed with a target Framework of .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I've found loads of pages referencing this topic but none are clear or conclusive hence this question.

If I install a c# application built with a target Framework of .Net Core 3.1 onto a server which contains just .NET 6, will it still run without any changes?

If I upgrade the version of .NET on a Windows server from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6, will the applications already on that server, built with a target Framework of .Net Core 3.1, still run OK?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily - there are many breaking changes on every major release.

Those for .NET 5->6 are published here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0). For .NET Core 3.1 -> .NET 5 see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0).

Note also the distinction between **binary incompatible** and **source incompatible**

> **Binary incompatible** - Existing binaries may encounter a breaking change in behavior, such as failure to load or execute, or different run-time behavior.
>
> **Source incompatible** - Source code may encounter a breaking change in behavior when targeting the new runtime or using the new SDK or
> component. Behavior changes can include compile errors or different
> run-time behavior.